# How can Greenshot (or Imgur) know my video file name via screenshot?

Tags: security, privacy, vulnerabilities, imgur, greenshot

I took some video from Internet, open it with `MPC-HC`, then take screenshot [with `Greenshot`](http://getgreenshot.org/), then choose upload to `Imgur`.

It gave me the link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4ccH.png

Then I change this to

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhAPK.jpg

in order to open framed image and I see filename in the title, which is the original file name from my disk:

[image]

("The.Angriest.Man.in.Brooklyn.BDRip_By_Flash.avi")

The question is: how could filename from my computer travel to Imgur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already found out, the window title reveals the filename, which is then be used as title for the screenshot.

It is worth noting that you can disable this behavior in [Greenshot's config file](http://getgreenshot.org/faq/where-does-greenshot-store-its-configuration-settings/):

```
; Is the title passed on to Imgur
AddTitle=False
; Is the filename passed on to Imgur
AddFilename=False
```

(Make sure to close Greenshot before manually modifying the configuration file, otherwise the changes might not be applied.)

As of the next release, the default configuration will have those two set to `False` for fresh installations (existing configuration files will not be modified when installing the new version).

Answer (score 3):

Experiments show, that Greenshot takes the window title. So if Video player shows filename -- it goes to Imgur as image title.

Answer (score 0):

Speculating.

The application used for capturing the screen knows what application is focused and when submitting the screen shot to Imgur it simply adds the file name of the file opened by the application.

Try opening a .jpeg in an image viewer and screen shot it, if I'm right the same behavior should occur!